# highlight locations on map make its related bar highlighted

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, bar-chart, highlight

I have bar chart representing the total number of visitors for the nodes locations  on the map. Each bar related to one location on the map.
I would like to implement hover on a location on the map will highlight its related bar and visa versa, any way I can do that? and how? I appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: Can you put this up on a working fiddle

Comment: unfortunately I can't, because they have separate files with huge data, but here is the link to github https://github.com/Mila1988/dataviscourse-pr-Exploration-of-National-Park-Recreation/